# CakePHP share code between Shells and its Tasks

Tags: shell, cakephp, task

I'm wondering if it's possible to share code (functions and variables) between a Shell and its Tasks.  For example, say I have the following:

```
Class MyShell extends Shell{

 var $tasks = array('MyTask');
 var $someVariable;

 function someFunction(){}
}
```

and then in my tasks:

```
class MyTask extends Shell {
   //somehow access the someFunction() and $someVariable in here
}
```

Is this possible?  Also, whether it is or isnt, is this not the recommended cake way?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why not extend the shell class with the task, like this?

```
<?php
class MyTask extends MyShell {
  function taskFunction() {
    $someFunctionResult = $this->someFunction();
  }
}
```